# Internal Server Error after upgrading from magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

I had upgraded my dev store from magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.3 after that i am getting below error
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@dev.vitalticks.in to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

If i rename or delete the .htaccess file only home page is loading when i click on any other links again i am getting above error only.

For reference please find the Url 
dev.vitalticks.in

Log File

[2019-11-28 01:31:35] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vitalticks/public_html/dev/app/code/Mageplaza/Search/Helper/Data.php on line 345 [] []
[2019-11-28 03:52:05] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vitalticks/public_html/dev/app/code/Mageplaza/Search/Helper/Data.php on line 345 [] []
[2019-11-28 05:37:25] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vitalticks/public_html/dev/app/code/Mageplaza/Search/Helper/Data.php on line 345 [] []
[2019-11-28 05:38:28] main.ERROR: Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled.  [] []
[2019-11-28 06:16:11] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:16:11] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:16:11] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:16:11] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:16:12] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:16:12] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:16:12] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 1667; Allocated memory size: 40008000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:18:00] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vitalticks/public_html/dev/app/code/Mageplaza/Search/Helper/Data.php on line 345 [] []
[2019-11-28 06:18:28] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vitalticks/public_html/dev/app/code/Mageplaza/Search/Helper/Data.php on line 345 [] []
[2019-11-28 06:34:57] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vitalticks/public_html/dev/app/code/Mageplaza/Search/Helper/Data.php on line 345 [] []
[2019-11-28 06:35:03] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vitalticks/public_html/dev/app/code/Mageplaza/Search/Helper/Data.php on line 345 [] []
[2019-11-28 06:46:41] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:46:41] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:46:41] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:46:41] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:46:41] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:46:41] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
[2019-11-28 06:46:42] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 1667; Allocated memory size: 40008000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []

Thanks in Advance
Somu N

Comment: Disable **Mageplaza/Search** this module and run all deployment command once and check.

Comment: even admin panel also not coming

Comment: You're getting same error there as well ?

Answer (score 0):

add if condition before foreach shown below

```
if ($this->getChildCategories($category)) {
    foreach ($this->getChildCategories($category) as $childCategory) {
        $this->getCategoryOptions($childCategory, $options, $level, $htmlPrefix);
    }
}
```